# If the symmedian at $A$ of $\triangle ABC$ meets the circumcircle at $K$, then $KA$ is a symmedian of $\triangle KBC$.

Tags: geometry

> Let the symmedian of $\triangle ABC$ at $A$ pass through the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $K$. Prove that $KA$ is a symmedian of $\triangle KBC$.

The book says that it is very obvious, but I seem to be too tunnel visioned on angle chasing. I can't find anything that proves it.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed obvious.  Recall

**Fact**: The symmedian from $A$ of $\triangle ABC$ is the line $AX$ where $X$ is the intersection of tangents to the circumcircle at $B,C$.

Now $A,K,X$ are collinear, $\triangle KBC$ and $\triangle ABC$ have the same circumcircle, so the line $KX$ (same as line $KA$) is the symmedian of $\triangle KBC$ through $K$.